# Can't import python module into root directory only specific directory working for importing module

Tags: python, python-2.7, centos7

I have vps installed centos 7. I am using python2.7 for running some scripts. But the problem is at some of the directories I can use python common modules like requests. but at the root directory, I can't import python requests module. It say no module name ***python requests***. But I am using it on another directory of the VPS.

```sh
[root@madcodlab-centos7 site-packages]# ls                                                                                                                                                           
backports                                            _dummy_thread                    ipaddress.pyc                   pushetta-1.0.15.dist-info                 terminaltables-3.1.0-py2.7.egg-info  
backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.5.0.1-py2.7.egg-info  easy_install.py                  ipaddress.pyo                   python_linux_procfs-0.4.9-py2.7.egg-info  _thread                              
builtins                                             easy_install.pyc                 libfuturize                     pyudev                                    tkinter                              
certifi                                              easy_install.pyo                 libpasteurize                   pyudev-0.15-py2.7.egg-info                tuned                                
certifi-2019.3.9.dist-info                           examples                         _markerlib                      queue                                     urlgrabber                           
chardet                                              firewall                         _markupbase                     reprlib                                   urlgrabber-3.10-py2.7.egg-info       
chardet-3.0.4.dist-info                              future                           paho                            requests                                  urllib3                              
configobj-4.7.2-py2.7.egg-info                       future-0.17.1-py2.7.egg-info     paho_mqtt-1.4.0-py2.7.egg-info  requests-2.22.0.dist-info                 urllib3-1.25.3.dist-info             
configobj.py                                         html                             past                            rpmUtils                                  validate.py                          
configobj.pyc                                        http                             pip                             setuptools                                validate.pyc                         
configobj.pyo                                        idna                             pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg-info        setuptools-0.9.8-py2.7.egg-info           validate.pyo                         
copyreg                                              idna-2.8.dist-info               pkg_resources.py                slip                                      winreg                               
decorator-3.4.0-py2.7.egg-info                       iniparse                         pkg_resources.pyc               slip-0.4.0-py2.7.egg-info                 xmlrpc                               
decorator.py                                         iniparse-0.4-py2.7.egg-info      pkg_resources.pyo               slip.dbus-0.4.0-py2.7.egg-info            yum                                  
decorator.pyc                                        ipaddress-1.0.16-py2.7.egg-info  procfs                          socketserver                                                                   
decorator.pyo                                        ipaddress.py                     pushetta                        terminaltables 

[root@madcodlab-centos7 site-packages]# python                                                                                                                                                       
Python 2.7.16 (default, May 24 2019, 21:44:39)                                                                                                                                                       
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)] on linux2                                                                                                                                                    
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.                                                                                                                               
>>> import requests                                                                                                                                                                                  
>>> exit()               

[root@madcodlab-centos7 site-packages]# cd 

[root@madcodlab-centos7 ~]# python                                                                                                                                                                   
Python 2.7.16 (default, May 24 2019, 21:44:39)                                                                                                                                                       
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)] on linux2                                                                                                                                                    
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.                                                                                                                               
>>> ex                                                                                                                                                                                             
>>> import requests                                                                                                                                                                                  
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                   
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                                                                                
ImportError: No module named requests                                                                                                                                                                
>>>
```

I have searched and tired lot of solution from everywhere on the net but it seems like nothing working.

`which python` yields `/usr/local/bin/python`

the site packages directory is `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Comment: I noticed that you have python in the path. Can you check `which python` ? maybe you have several python versions in your system, one without `requests` module.

Comment: /usr/local/bin/python

Here it is. I guess it python2.7 I have installed

Comment: so is `site-packages` you're showing the contents of located in `/usr/local/bin/python` ?

Comment: it's  /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

Comment: When I  am installing python2.7 I turned off alternative install which make python27 into python